# adobe flash cs6, air and flex

Tags: air, adobe, flex4, flash-cs6

I want to know how to find out which version of Flex is installed with Flash CS6 or do I have to install the SDK separately?

I know Adobe AIR 3.2 is installed on in the Flash CS6 program folder as I found the Adobe AIR 3.2 folder in the Flash CS6 program folder.

In Flash CS Preferences, if I click on the Actionscript 3 settings button it shows the Flex SDK path as:

```
$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/flex_sdk/4.0.0/
```

Does this mean that Flex 4 is installed on the computer? I ask this because I couldn't find a folder for Flex 4 SDK.

Also, if AIR 3.2 is installed, do I need Flex?

Can I achieve the same results with AIR 3.2 as I can with Flex?

I want to develop Flash applications that will allow the user to save and load data locally as a text file, create a line chart of that data and then save a screenshot of that chart from within Flash without using any other tool such as the Snipping Tool in Windows.

I did a lot of research on these subjects on different forums, including Stack Overflow, but just ended up more confused than I already was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is now Animate. It's like photoshop. Photoshop creates images in many forms. Flash/Animate is software that makes .swf, html5 canvas, AIR, Android apps, iOS apps, and more.

Flex is a Flash framework.

The reason you have to mess with the SDK is because you're using an old non-working version of Flash. If you use a working version of Animate, you don't have to install SDKs manually.

AIR is what you want to use. .swf was Flash applications for browsers/web pages. AIR is Flash applications for OSs. AIR creates .exe for desktop and native apps for phones.

With AIR you can make a word processor and image processor.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I know, a ".swf" file can be published as a "Win Projector" and "Mac Projector" file. So why would one need AIR if applications are being developed for the desktop environment only? Also I have come across some ".fla" files on the net that do have some sort of load and save capabilities, in addition to the creation of charts. They have been made with older versions of Flash because I get a prompt to save the file in a newer version if I try to save. I dug deeper on the net and think that Flex is more for developers than designers. Am i correct?

Comment: .swf has no access. It's like javascript. The Projector is just a web browser. AIR is on the OS, not in a browser. It can read, write, etc. Look at file handling for both to see the difference. Flex is a framework so it's for people that can't code or don't know Flash and to expedite development. I can code so I never used Flex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.